# Assertion failure when using puphpet

Tags: nginx, hhvm

I am trying to use the hhvm, but then i try and run my test script i get an `502 Bad Gateway` (nginx) error message

so i tried to run it in terminal and i get the following error message:

```
$ hhvm /var/www/public/test.php 

Assertion failure: /tmp/tmp.3Ty7dCXWJ2/hphp/runtime/base/rds.cpp:426: void HPHP::rds::initPersistentCache(): assertion `s_tc_fd != -1' failed.


Aborted
```

but when i run it using sudo it works!

```
$ sudo hhvm /var/www/public/test.php 
hello world
```

What did i do wrong? i have tried updating the owner of a file and changed the permissions of hhvm, but this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting assertion failures in a release build of HHVM. Can you please [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues) so we can track the bug? Make sure to include your OS as well as the output of `hhvm --version`.